# Jefrey way generators wrong output to the migration

Tags: laravel-4, migration

I am using jefrey way generators to create my migrations and its not generating the output accordingly here is my migration

```
php artisan generate:migration create_employees_table --fields="first_name:string,
last_name:string,gender:string,phone:integer,address:string,photo:string,age:integer,
salary:integer"
```

And the migration created is as follows

```
class CreateEmployeesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string,gender('last_name')->string,phone()->integer,address()->string,photo()->string,age()->integer,salary()->integer();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('employees');
}
```

My problem is what am i doing wrong in the generator command that its not outputting the migration correctly,also to clarify i am using git shell on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put space after comma

```
  php artisan generate:migration create_employees_table --fields="first_name:string, last_name:string, gender:string, phone:integer, address:string, photo:string, age:integer, salary:integer"
```